# Animation node cut object

Tags: animation-nodes

There's target object and cutter object, boolean modifier can work for one frame, but how can I use animation node to cut the target with cutter object and keep the all history cutting. I have tried almost all nodes, can't find the solution.

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

You may think why not using a invisible full size object to cut it. A case is CNC simulation, engraving a human face like a coin.

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate.  the effect achieved in this example and the effect achieved in the "duplicate" have differences.

Comment: Do you want to use pure Animation Nodes without a boolean modifier?

Comment: Any method is ok if it could work. I use a boolean modifier as you can see in the 1st demo gif.